# Need optimize query using annotate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Have 2 models : MyItem and Category

This works, but how do I do this with a single query using annotate:

```
for cat in Category.objects.all():
    cat.count = MyItem.objects.filter(category=cat).count()
    cat.save()
```

Like some:

```
Category.objects.annotate(_items_count=Count('myitem')).update(count=_items_count)
```

Comment: Except for the bracket, what is not working with this?

Comment: unresolved reference _items_count

Comment: Ah, what if you use `F('_items_count')` in the `update`?

Comment: Hmm, this should work on the idea, it's just in the data migration, I now have no way to check

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `F('_items_count')` will give an error need use subquery.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652736/django-update-queryset-with-annotation