# Django - How to use update on an annotated queryset instead of using a for loop?

Tags: django, django-models

I have to build a field from an annotation, the field is a score which is equal to the division of two other annotations which are based on different Querysets Expressions.

```
annotated_queryset = Influencer.objects.annotate(
    score_sum=Sum('submission__answer__decisions__score'),
    submission_count=Count('submission',
        filter=Q(
            submission__status__in=Submission.ANSWERED_STATUS
        )
    )
).annotate(rate=F('score_sum') / F('submission_count'))
```

This snippet shows how i get my annotation.

Now i'd love to be able to do the following :

```
annotated_queryset.update(acceptation_rate=F('rate'))
```

But I get a `FieldError: Aggregate functions are not allowed in this query`

My only solutions is to use the ugly and expensive for loop :

```
for each in annotated_queryset:
    each.acceptation_rate = each.rate
    each.save()
```

My questions are :

- Why can't I use the annotate + update form ?
- Is there any better way than the for loop to do this ? What would it be ?

Edit, Using Subqueries :

```
annotated_queryset = Influencer.objects.annotate(
    score_sum=Sum('submission__answer__score'),
    submission_count=Count('submission',
        filter=Q(
            submission__status__in=Submission.ANSWERED_STATUS
        )
    )
).annotate(
    rate=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('score_sum') / F('submission_count'),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)[:1]

Influencer.objects.update(acceptation_rate=Subquery(annotated_queryset))
```

Comment: Because a database typically does not allow when you JOIN together, but by a subquery, you can get this working.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134728/67579

Comment: I tried using subqueries but I now get an obscure
`SQL Exception : 
LINE 1: ...T "acceptation_rate" = (SELECT (SUM(U4."score") / COUNT(U1."...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Should i update my question with the code i used to get this ?

Comment: Can you share the subquery approach?

Comment: You probably need to add `[:1]` at the end of the `annotated_queryset`, since here you do not really annotated the *entire* table, but each *row*.

Comment: I have the same error whit the [:1]. While searching i found several other issues and updated my question to reflect the changes. But i'm still stuck with the same SQL exception.
Thanks for your help anyway !