# update field with number of row in another table django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building a web crawler contain links blogs etc of x website  ... , I have field  called number_of_crawled_Links and I want to make the value of that filed is the number of rows in another model Where Links Stored  i want the process to be automatically without making request  any idea how to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652736/django-update-queryset-with-annotation/50134728

Comment: I don't think it is an answer to the question...

Comment: @Iain Shelvington it is not what I'm looking for , bcs i already updating it using mysql method but i wanna avoid this and use pure django

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in fields directly, but it's good idea to do that as a method.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field = models.TextField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_some_field_value(self):
        return self.model_a.some_field
```

Then `ModelB` can get dynamically the value of `ModelA` field `some_field`. You can do it with any type of values.

Comment: somone closed my question and refer me to a useless answser,  however i want omake that work automaticly every 10 minutes for examlple

Comment: I do not want field value but the count of all rows in another table ( model)

Comment: You can do anything in such method and return whatever you like. I don't know the details, so I cannot give you ready code. Share more related code or figure out the rest yourself. And for `cron` you have to get something like `django-scheduler` and put it in your `AppConfig`.